# Keep Jupyter notebook running with Macbook closed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sleep, execution

As simple as the title: Are there ways to keep jupyter notebook cells running with a closed laptop? Sometimes I need to run to a meeting or leave the office and I have to close my laptop. I'd love to be able to keep cells running.

Is this just a matter of biting the bullet and running my code on AWS/Google compute rather than locally? Or is there a way to set my Macbook to not enter sleep state on closed under certain conditions?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, terminal processes are 'paused' when you close the lid of the MacBook and it enters sleep mode. Re-opening the lid should resume the process, unless there is an error/exception thrown (for example due to failed network access).

A workaround might be to prevent the OS from going to sleep in the first place by using something like [caffeine](https://github.com/jpn--/caffeine).

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can just go to your system preferences-> energy saver-> set computer sleep and display sleep sliders to “never”.

Best!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [Amphetamine](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704) to keep my Mac up and running for various ML tasks